OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory while using compute_metrics function in Hugging Face Trainer
I'm encountering a CUDA out of memory error when using the compute_metrics function with the Hugging Face Trainer during model evaluation. My GPU is running out of memory while trying to compute the ROUGE scores. Below is a summary of my setup and the error message:
I have a val_dataset with 352 samples.
The model is GPT-2
I want to test the Rouge metric but when I try it gives me the error. Currently using Google Collab

How can I efficiently compute ROUGE or BLEU metrics without running out of GPU memory?

Are there any recommended strategies or configurations to handle large-scale evaluation on limited GPU memory?


The code looks like this

tokenized_train_dataset = train_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=MAX,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config).to('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
mode_size = sum(t.numel() for t in model.parameters())
print(f"Model size: {mode_size/1000**2:.1f}M parameters")

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False,
)

class EarlyStoppingCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def __init__(self, patience=3):
        super().__init__()  
        self.patience = patience
        self.best_loss = np.inf
        self.epochs_no_improve = 0

    def on_evaluate(self, args, state, control, metrics=None, **kwargs):
        eval_loss = metrics.get("eval_loss", None)
        if eval_loss is not None:
            if eval_loss < self.best_loss:
                self.best_loss = eval_loss
                self.epochs_no_improve = 0
            else:
                self.epochs_no_improve += 1
                if self.epochs_no_improve >= self.patience:
                    control.should_training_stop = True  


early_stopping_callback = EarlyStoppingCallback(patience=3)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./model",
    hub_model_id="profile/model",
    eval_strategy="epoch",
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    save_steps=500,
    save_total_limit=3,
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    fp16=True,
    push_to_hub=True,
    logging_steps=100,
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_validation_dataset,
    callbacks=[early_stopping_callback]
)


trainer.train()


Did you already try to reduce per_device_eval_batch_size?
You could also set eval_accumulation_steps (to a low number) and see if that helps, check out this thread: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/cuda-out-of-memory-when-using-trainer-with-compute-metrics/2941/12
If nothing works, you could use a smaller validation set and run a custom evaluation using (smaller chunks of) a test set, although this might influence how well your model learns. Or you use a smaller model like https://huggingface.co/distilbert/distilgpt2. From my experience in Google Colab you might also randomly get a GPU assigned that has a bit more or less VRAM (e.g. 16GB vs 24GB), which could make the difference for whether you run out of memory or not, check out the second point here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71540646/18189622

I gonna try set the per_device_eval_batch_size and eval_accumulation_steps to lower, and lower the val set. The thing is that even using A100 with 40 gib it kept giving me the error. So, my guess is that the way im evaluating the BLEU and ROUGE is wrong. Any suggestions in that matter? Thanks!

I dont see the parts where you compute BLEU/ROUGE or call compute_metrics in the code, so I can't really tell. I did use BLEU during a model fine-tuning before and did not have performance issues from it, check out the repository: https://github.com/EliasK93/transformer-models-for-domain-specific-machine-translation/blob/master/domain_specific_machine_translation/iii_model_training/train_models.py#L50
